# Does fancytree have an event that indicates it has completely loaded the data in the tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, fancytree, unselect

I want to know if in any way figure out that fancytree is completely finished loading data and the component is fully loaded so i can change its options.
Currently I am trying to change selectMode (from 3 to 2 for example) but when I do so data will not be fully loaded and checked. 
It looks like I am changing selectMode before data is fully loaded.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `init` event, or `loadChildren` for example. See [the tutorial](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialEvents) or 
[the list of available events](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/global.html#FancytreeEvents) for details.
(Note however, that changing the selectMode will not (un)check any existing nodes.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that changing the select mode won't check/uncheck existing nodes. I just want to make sure I am changing selectMode after fancytree is finihsed. I will go through the link. Thanks a lot.